# Open new windows with Kupfer

Tags: 12.04, kupfer

I was using gnome-do before I switched to Kupfer which is awesome, the problem is that when I try to open something like terminal and I already have one open it will switch focus to the existing one.

Is there any way to set it up that it will open a new window instead?

Answer (score 6):

After typing your application name, switch to the "action" by hitting tab and type "launch again".

To make it the permanent default for this application, select "Make 'Launch Again' Default for..." from the kupfer menu in the top-right corner.